# Typeahead AngularStrap: too many $http calls

Tags: angularjs, typeahead, angular-strap

I'm using angularstrap typeahead for autocomplete suggestions via $http. [Demo here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/N5QcvwR90oQah12r1f1N?p=preview)

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="selectedAddress" data-animation="am-flip-x" bs-options="address.formatted_address as address.formatted_address for address in getAddress($viewValue)" placeholder="Enter address" bs-typeahead>
```

Everything works fine but everytime I type a letter, a call is made. Even if I set a minLength of 3, a call is made for length one and two.

How do I prevent that behaviour? Other thing that happens is when template/controller is loaded, the function getAddress is called...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ng-model-options as attribute of :

```
ng-model-options="{ debounce: 2000 }"
```

This code will help you to make the call only at an interval of 1 second. Even if you type 4-5 chars during that time it'll still call only once every 2 seconds.

Comment: Nice, it works! Do you know how to fix that first empty call on controller load? Thanks

Comment: I'm not entirely sure actually but you can try setting the bs-typeahead attribute conditionally. If model is not empty then only set this option.